# Why does the following code work in Windows XP but not 7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have connected a USB printer, and I am trying to open that port using `Open` method of `CFile` class.
The following code works properly in Windows XP, but it does not work in Windows 7:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<afx.h>
void main()
{
    CFile m_Port;
    CString PortName = "\\\\?\\usb#vid_0b0b&pid_106e#sx0000000-tc0000#{28d78fad-5a12-11d1-ae5b-0000f803a8c2}";
    int i;
    i = m_Port.Open (PortName ,2,0);//PortName is DevicePath
    if ( i > 0 )
        printf("Done");
    else
        printf("Its not working");

    i=GetLastError();
    printf("\n\nError=%d",i);
}
```

In Windows XP it works properly, but in the case of Windows 7, `GetLastError` returns a value of 3. How can I fix this code to work on both Windows XP and Windows 7?
Let me know if their are any different GUID in windows 7. Are their any other option to open port using device path in windows 7?

Comment: 3 -> "The system cannot find the path specified." I'd guess you're running into security issues on Windows 7. Or rather, running into an implementation of the brilliant idea that you're secure when you can't do what you want with your PC, but any interested hacker can. Another possiblity is the UUID you're using. Or the id in general: are you sure it's the same in Windows 7?

Comment: My advice: Check with ProcessExplorer what exactly happens under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Windows 7, but perhaps you have to run the application elevated.
I guess, the path is wrong (and this is what error 3 says). 
Open the device manager, select the device and "Properties" in the context menu. Then "Details" and there "Hardware IDs". 
Do you find the path from your code sample here? If not, change your code accordingly.

Also: For this kind of system-near programming I would use ::CreateFile from WIN-API and not CFile class.